# Define a fixed scale [0..1] within a boxplot (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, data-science, boxplot

I have several record sets with values between 0 and 1. 
When I generate a boxplot out of those rs I received different scales in the boxplot (in case A from 0.1 to 0.7, in case B from 0.15 to 0.9, in case C from 0.05 to 0.9 etc.).

Can I set a standardized scale like from 0 to 1 for one axis (y)?

Like in Excel, when I can set for a graph that the scale shout start always at 0?

Comment: Yes, suppose you have your plot `myplot`, you can do `myplot + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))`. Setting the limits to `c(0, NA)` will choose 0 as lower limit and the data maximum as upper limit.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. Those suggestions has worked fine! Thank you!